# Why Do method of Conn interface is inlined

Tags: go, redis

I created a redigo application with following code

```
conn, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
defer conn.Close()

_, err = conn.Do("HMSET", "album:1", "title", "Electric Ladyland", "artist", "Jimi Hendrix", "price", 4.95, "likes", 8)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

created a binary from above code and took the objdump of binary. I found that there is no definition of conn.Do in objdump as it became inline.
In redigo code, I changed the following function in conn.go but it did not work

```
//go:noinline 
func (c *conn) Do(cmd string, args ...interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    return c.DoWithTimeout(c.readTimeout, cmd, args...)
}
```

Can someone suggest how make Do method noline?

Comment: FWIW, the interface call through Conn.Do in the program above is not inlined on my machine when I compile with GOARCH amd64 or arm64.

Answer (score 0):

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68280986/6309), a `//go:noinline` pragma before a function declaration should have disabled inlining of that specific function.

But: if you are modifying [`github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis/conn.go`](https://github.com/gomodule/redigo/blob/574218b5788d47ef16ad8eb15a6704314a3e42d5/redis/conn.go), used in your project as a library (`go get github.com/gomodule/redigo`, added to your project `go.mod`/`go.sum`), that would not work.
Go would still compile the official cached module dependency for `github.com/gomodule/redigo`, not your local modification.
Hence, your `//go:noinline` is ignored.

You would need to fork the project, and `go get` that fork, *and* use a `replace` directive, as illustrated in "[Go Module’s Replace](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/go-modules-replace-3ea6d0139c91)" from [nwillc](https://github.com/nwillc):

> ```
> replace github.com/pgavlin/femto => github.com/nwillc/femto v0.0.0-20201217031030-474e70183a86
> ```
>
> That "replaced" the `github.com/pgavlin/femto` with my fork `github.com/nwillc/femto`.
> And finally, back in `snipgo` I tried again:
>
> ```
> go get -u github.com/nwillc/snipgo
> ```

Only then, any modification done to the source of (your forked) redigo repository would "stick" and be compiled.

Comment: I didn't understand it completely. I add this change in go.mod file:   replace github.com/gomodule/redigo => github.com/gomodule/redigo1
I created copy of redigo as redigo1 also followed the steps given on https://levelup.gitconnected.com/go-modules-replace-3ea6d0139c91  but could not solve that. Could you please give some example

Comment: @ManojKumar Basically, you cannot modified librairies part of your project dependencies (listed in your `go.mod`)

Comment: Besides creating a form and making the changes into original code, dont I have any other solution?

Comment: @ManojKumar That would be opening a pull request, yes (not "a form"). But note that https://github.com/gomodule/redigo1 does not exist. https://github.com/gomodule/redigo does. However, that fork has no new commit which would have recently (like "today") modified the code you want to see modified. Try and commit locally your change in the local cloned forked repository, and push back. Then force an update (`go get -u github.com/gomodule/redigo`).

Comment: Thanks. will try that

Comment: https://github.com/gomodule/redigo/pull/578

Comment: @ManojKumar That is one approach. Make sure you have tested it locally first, with your fork and the `replace` directive forcing `go build` to consider your local force rather than the official dependency.

Comment: I have closed the pull request. As per above link I added following line in go.mod                                                                     "replace github.com/gomodule/redigo => github.com/ManojKumarChauhan/redigo "            but it's not working

Comment: @ManojKumar Try a `go list` first, as shown in https://levelup.gitconnected.com/go-modules-replace-3ea6d0139c91#d2c4

Comment: go list all github.com/ManojKumarChauhan/redigo/redis   -> result ->
go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlpmetric/internal/connection/connection.go:26:2: found import comments "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/internal/otlpconfig" (options.go) and "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlpmetric/internal/otlpconfig" (optiontypes.go) in /root/go/src/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlpmetric/internal/otlpconfig

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238703/discussion-between-vonc-and-manojkumar).